# Pandas DataFrame value cannot be set

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to do a target encoding using k-fold.
Below is the code:

```
# Reset the values first
all_data['item_target_enc'] = np.nan # Setting the initial column value to nan

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(all_data):    
    # test_index is the "current fold"
    # train_index is the "all but current fold"
    item_id_target_mean = all_data.iloc[train_index].groupby('item_id').target.mean()
    label = all_data.index[test_index]
    all_data.loc[label]['item_target_enc'] = all_data.loc[label]['item_id'].map(item_id_target_mean)

print ('Not Nan')
print(all_data[~all_data['item_target_enc'].isnull()]) # This produced Empty DataFrame
```

The output is that all the `item_target_enc` is nan. So apparently this assignment does not seem to work

```
all_data.loc[label]['item_target_enc'] = all_data.loc[label]['item_id'].map(item_id_target_mean)
```

But I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: Try as the warning say`all_data.loc[label, 'item_target_enc'] = ...`

Comment: It's strange that there is no warning, but I tried your suggestion and it works! Thanks! The previous time I got warning is that when I use iloc.